# Sequelize ORM and MySQL group replication

Tags: mysql, node.js, configuration, sequelize.js, replication

I am using `sequelize` as an ORM for `nodejs` application and MySQL for the database.
Recently I've set up group replication on MySQL, but I couldn't find relative documentation for `sequelize`.

On `sequelize`'s official documentation It's written only about standard replication with primary and replica nodes, however during group replication, if the primary node goes down it will automatically change the primary role to the next server. So is there a way for Sequelize to detect this event and appropriately set a new write server?

We've set up group replication for solving the failover problem, it would be nice to implement it with Sequelize as well.